# Chrome calc() in CSS not working correct with display table

Tags: google-chrome, row

As you can see with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ogpbj4yd/1/) example when you click the run button (same as refresh when view the example local) the table `row-min` resizes until its height becomes `70px` as in CSS.

Why is this happening? Why chrome won't make it the height stated in the CSS with the first loading of the page? This bug not seen in Firefox or Edge. Is this a bug of the browser?

**update**: as I can see now is something to do with the `calc()` of the `row-max` height. If you set it to static it won't cause problem..

**update1**: managed to overpass this by calculating the height of the `row-max` class in javascript like this `$('.row-max').css('height',($('.table').height()-70)+'px');`

The `calc()` error with chrome is remaining..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer is that you don't have to set the height of both `row-min` and `row-max` you just set the `row-min` height and the `row-max` is set automaticaly.
Just check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ogpbj4yd/5/) js fiddle which is a change of the jsfiddle i posted at my question.